# Error: The view didn't return an HttpResponse, when trying to send email

Tags: python, django

I want to manually approve reports for clients after they have agreed to terms. For this I want to email to be sent to myself when client clicks "accept". I get the following error instead:

> The view accounts.views.TermsView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Have searched for the same error here, but failed to solve with these. Sorry, new programmer here.

**views.py**

```
class TermsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "accounts/terms_of_service.html"

    ...

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.user.terms_accepted = timezone.now()
        self.request.user.save(update_fields=["terms_accepted"])
    
    def send_mail(self):
        messages.add_message(
            self.request,
            messages.SUCCESS,
            _("Thank you! We will contact you as soon as possible."),
        )

        send_terms_agreed_reports(self.request.company, self.request.user)
        return redirect("stays:dashboard")
```

**emails.py**

```
def send_terms_agreed_reports(company, user):
    try:
        email_subject = "New company wants to use reports"

        return send_email(
            settings.TERMS_AGREED_ENABLE_REPORTS,
            email_subject,
            "emails/terms_agreed_reports.html",
            {"company": company.name, "reg_code": company.reg_code, "name": user.name, "email": user.email,
         "phone": user.phone},
        )
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Could not send message")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `post` method eventually should return a HTTP response, for example by running `send_mail`:

```
class TermsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "accounts/terms_of_service.html"

    # …

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.user.terms_accepted = timezone.now()
        self.request.user.save(update_fields=['terms_accepted'])
        return self.send_mail()
```